# How to limit geodata to cities and railways in Mapnik?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, cartocss

I have successfully set up a working mapnik tile server under Ubuntu 14.04 using the OSMBright style. For testing purposes, I downloaded and imported the geodata for Luxembourg. The file was only 16MB in size and the import only took a minute.

Next, I wanted to add the geodata for Germany, which is way bigger (about 4GB). During the import, I ran out of disk space (which was quite sparse because I had to use a VM at work).

For our purpose, we actually only need railway lines, stations and cities without any more detail such as individual houses, streets, other POI's. As a beginner with OSM and Mapnik server: is there a way to omit unneccessary data when importing geodata in order to minimize the required resources? Or can I only create a style that does not display the unneccessary things (which wouldn't save disk space but would probably increase performance)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) and [osmfilter](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter) for filtering data *after* downloading and [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) for filtering data *before* downloading.

For the appropriate tags see the wiki pages about [railways](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Railways), [stations](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Railway_stations) and [cities](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Places). Maybe you are interested in [landuse](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Landuse) and [administrative boundaries](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative), too.

Comment: The Overpass API is an interesting possibility! Meanwhile I also found the *osmfilter* tool that can easily extract desired entities from a geodata file.

Comment: @Robert Indeed, I added osmfilter to my answer :)